# Using the text replaced in the replace text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using the version 7.3.3 of Notepad++.

I have this list of numbers to 1.000.000.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

I want to add XML tags to these numbers like this:

```
<SerialNumber>
    <SN>1</SN>
</SerialNumber>
<SerialNumber>
    <SN>2</SN>
</SerialNumber>
<SerialNumber>
    <SN>3</SN>
</SerialNumber>
<SerialNumber>
    <SN>4</SN>
</SerialNumber>
```

So I need a regular expression to find a number ended with a `\n\r`, and use the number I've found with the regular expression in the text that I'm going to add.

Do you know to do that in Notepad++?

I have tried with `\d{*}` but it is not a valid regular expression.

Comment: Please tell us what language you want to use. Or do you ask how to do it quicly with notepadd++ ?

Comment: @Amitsouko I want to do it in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the "Replace" menu (Search > Replace...).

And set like that :
- Find what: `(\d+)[(\r)?\n]`
- Replace with : `<SerialNumber>\r\n    <SN>$1</SN>\r\n</SerialNumber>`
- Check : Search mode -> `Regular expression`

Then press `Replace All`. To even match the last number, add an empty line at the end of your file.

I  hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if we take your [1.... n] numbers in string called strData then :

```
var nums = strData.split("\r\n").map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
var strXmlOut = nums.map(function(n) {
   return "<SerialNumber><SN>" + n + "</SN></SerialNumber>";
}).join("\r\n");
```

and the one call version would be :

```
var xmlOut = strData.split("\r\n")
.map(function(item) {return parseInt(item, 10);})
.map(function(n) {return "<SerialNumber><SN>" + n + "</SN></SerialNumber>";})
.join("\r\n");
```